# How do I fulfill Boreas's "Use sweets" condition?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

On Boreas's Affinity Chart, the unlock condition for Gobble 'em Up says to "Use sweets". Many of Boreas's other abilities are unlocked by using a category of pouch item (staple foods, drinks, seafood), but there isn't a category for sweets.

How do I fulfill Boreas's Affinity Chart condition to use sweets?

[image: use sweets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any pouch item in the [Dessert](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Dessert) category counts as a sweet. Use Dessert pouch items while Boreas is engaged to meet the requirement.